# ARRAYFORMULA with FILTER and ARRAY_CONSTRAIN with dynamic dates

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to make an ARRAYFORMULA but can't make it with FILTER and ARRAY_CONSTRAIN inside.

I need to get value for biggest date in range less than condition. I hope example will be better for understanding.

My current formula is here and i need convert it to ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=IF(H2="",,IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(FILTER($H$2:$I,$G$2:$G=A2,$I$2:$I<=B2),1,0,2,0),1,1),"No data"))
```

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18epXaPUFLR2DeO5Mjy3nyhPskXVtA9P8WAil5q5JmKo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(or(a="",b="",,),,ifna(vlookup(b,filter({I:I,H:H},G:G=a),2,1),"No data"))))
```

[image]

Comment: last question, i've added to table a vlookup from third table for error case, but it doesn't work with your formula... can i do vlookup here like updated formula in column C?

Comment: Added the formula fix in Cell_F2

Comment: and can you check O2 cell, pls